# Images issue when deployed using publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 3.0 and my images work fine when I run from Visual Studio IDE. But when I publish to a file system, my images are not being displayed. Here is the snippet of code that doesnt work when published, but otherwise works fine.

```
.red_plus {float:left;padding-left:18px;color:#D82A26;background:url('/img/gll-red-plus.gif') 0 50% no-repeat;cursor:pointer;}



<span id="toggle_rates_summary" class="red_plus" onclick="SomeFunctionName('SomeParam'); return false">View Something</span>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?? Below is the folder structure of my project.

WebProjectName
 -Content
    -css
       -main.css
-Image
  -gll-red-plus.gif

Comment: After you Publish, is the gll-red-plus.gif file in the img folder?

Comment: Yes it's there in the image folder

Comment: Have you tried 'img/gll-red-plus.gif' instead of '/img/gll-red-plus.gif' (without /)?

Comment: Yes the same result...it cannot find the way. Is there any way in which I can know the application path or root path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image urls that you set in your CSS files should be relative to the location of the CSS file. So for example if you have the following folder structure:

```
|- Styles - main.css
|- img - gll-red-plus.gif
|- Views - ...
|- Content - ...
```

inside your `main.css`:

```
.red_plus {
    float:left;
    padding-left:18px; 
    color:#D82A26;
    background:url('../img/gll-red-plus.gif') 0 50% no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: @Darin...thanks for your reply. However, it does not work for me. I have edited the question with my folder structure.

Comment: Okay, this Kind of Worked for me...  background:url('../../img/gll-red-plus.gif') 0 50% no-repeat;